# Removing Similarities Python

Tags: python, list, compare

The list contains other lists:

```
L = [[3, 3], [4, 2], [3, 2]]
```

If the first element of the sublist is equal to the first element of other sublists the one that has higher second element has to be remove from the whole list.

So the new list is:

```
L = [[4,2], [3,2]]
```

How to do this as efficiently as possible?

Comment: Running for loops, first take first sublist compare it to the others then take second compare it from the start then take third compare it again from start and so on.

Comment: Efficient in terms of memory or time or both?

Comment: Time is more important for me in this case.

Answer (score 5):

```
L.sort(key=lambda x: x[1], reverse=True)
L = OrderedDict(L).items()
```

**Why that works**

If you do a `dict(L)` with `L` a list or tuple, this is more or less equivalent to:

```
{k: v for k, v in L}
```

As you can see, later values override prior values if duplicate keys (`k`) are present.

We can make use of this if we are able to put `L` in the correct order.

In your case, we don't really care about the order of the keys, but we want *lower values* (i.e. second elements of the sublists) to appear later. This way, any lower value overwrites a higher value with the same key.

It is sufficient to sort by the second elements of the sublists (in reverse order). Since `list.sort()` is stable this also preserves the original order of the entries as much as possible.

```
L.sort(key=lambda x: x[1], reverse=True)
```

`collections.OrderedDict(L)` now makes the elements unique by first element, keeping insertion order.

The `sort()` is `O(n ln n)` and the dict creation adds another `O(n)`. It's possible to do without the sort:

```
d = OrderedDict()    
for k, v in L:    
    ev = d.get(k, None)    
    # update value. Always if key is not present or conditionally
    # if existing value is larger than current value
    d[k] = v if ev is None or ev > v else ev    

L = d.items()
```

But that is a lot more code and probably not at all or not much faster in pure Python.

Edits: (1) make it work with non-integer keys (2) It's enough to sort by second elements, no need for a full sort.

Comment: The second version is neat, but an explanation would be nice for those who aren't so familiar with the details of Python.

Comment: @jonrsharpe Added, it's also possible to generalize and simplify. I did that, too.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't care about the ordering of the elements in the output list, then you can create a dictionary that maps first items to second items, then construct your result from the smallest values.

```
from collections import defaultdict
L = [[3, 3], [4, 2], [3, 2]]
d = defaultdict(list)
for k,v in L:
    d[k].append(v)
result = [[k, min(v)] for k,v in d.iteritems()]
print result
```

Result:

```
[[3, 2], [4, 2]]
```

This is pretty efficient - O(n) average case, O(n*log(n)) worst case.

Comment: Yes, I do not  care about ordering.

Answer (score -2):

You can use this too.

```
x = [[3, 3], [4, 2], [3, 2]]
for i in x:
   if i[0]==i[1]:
       x.pop(x.index(i))
```

Comment: I don't think you've understood the question - although it will work on *that specific set of input*, it's not using the correct algorithm so will fail in the general case.